# How to find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1})$?

Tags: calculus

How do I find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n+1}\right)$ ?

I could not find a proper substitution. $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2+n+1}=t$ seems not to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:$$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2 + n + 1}\right)$$

$$= \arctan\left(\dfrac{(n+1)-n}{1+(n+1)n}\right)$$

$$=\arctan\left(n+1\right)-\arctan\left(n\right)$$

The sum telescopes :

$$S = \lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan(n)-\arctan(1)$$

$$=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition! Great! Thanks a lot!